# Rewriting HTML/SCSS navbar into react styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have my personal website which I wrote many years ago using HTML + ejs templates and scss. I am now in the process of re-writing the website using nextjs and react styled-components.

I am having trouble reproducing the behaviour of my nav bar my previous code in react and seeking help please. This is mostly a react/css problem.

### desired behaviour

I want my navbar to be as such:

1. A single bar across the screen with all links/buttons in-line.

   1. Links to different pages on the left side and some data/other links on the right side.
2. Some of the buttons on the left side should be drop-downs which are shown on hover.

   1. The drop-down content should be displayed directly below the button as a small rectangle with links aligned stacked.
3. The navbar should be responsive.

   1. When the user makes the window smaller than x amount (968px here) the navbar collapses and only displays a main link to the blog page (home page) and a hamburger button on the right side.
   2. When the user clicks on the hamburger button the menu drops down and shows all the links available.
   3. The drop-down menus should still function in this responsive mode when hovered over or clicked on on a mobile device.

I have another question I got while simplifying my code. Is my understanding correct in using a hook to make sure the component is mounted before rendering? I noticed that if I remove this hook the navbar will render without the styles applied to it. I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this or if there is a better way.

### minimal code example

Ok here is a minimal example for debugging the navbar:

```bash
npx create-next-app --ts .
# ✔ Would you like to use ESLint with this project? … No / Yes
# ✔ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? … No / Yes
# ✔ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project? … No / Yes
# ✔ What import alias would you like configured? … @components/*
# Creating a new Next.js app in /Users/work/Desktop/next-minimal-navbar.
npm install styled-components
```

Simplified the following files:

`index.tsx`:

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Hello, world!</title>
            </Head>
            <main>
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                </p>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}
```

`_document.tsx`:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html lang="en">
            <Head />
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}
```

#### simplified navbar code (problem code)

This is where we import the `Navbar` component:

`_app.tsx`:

```
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import NavBar from './NavBar';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <NavBar />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </>
    )
}
```

And finally the `NavBar` component:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const NavContainer = styled.nav`
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 90%;

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        width: 95%;
    }
`;

const CommonNavItem = styled.div<{ rightmost?: boolean }>`
    cursor: pointer;
    float: ${(props) => (props.rightmost ? 'right' : 'left')};
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
`;

// allows for argument to determine if align left or right
// inherit from Link component allows for linking to other pages
const NavItem = styled(CommonNavItem).attrs({ as: Link }) <{ rightmost?: boolean }>``;

const NavImage = styled.img`
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
`;

const DropDownContainer = styled.div`
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
`;

// the same as NavItem but no link
const DropDownLabel = styled(CommonNavItem)<{ rightmost?: boolean }>``;

const DropDownContent = styled.div`
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;

    ${DropDownContainer}:hover & {
        display: block;
    }

    ${NavItem} {
        float: none;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-align: left;
    }
`;

// since using conditionals in components we must ensure that the component is mounted before rendering
// either this or use dynamic from next/dynamic
function NavBar() {
    const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setHasMounted(true);
    }, []);

    if (!hasMounted) {
        return null;
    }
    
    return (
        <NavContainer>
            <NavItem href='/'>Blog</NavItem>
            <NavItem href='/'>Link1</NavItem>
            <NavItem href='/'>Link2</NavItem>
            <NavItem href='/'>Link3</NavItem>
            <NavItem href='/'>Link4</NavItem>
            <DropDownContainer>
                <DropDownLabel>Drop Down Label</DropDownLabel>
                <DropDownContent>
                    <NavItem href='/some-link'>Drop Down Item 1</NavItem>
                    <NavItem href='/chemistry'>Drop Down Item 1</NavItem>
                </DropDownContent>
            </DropDownContainer>

            <NavItem rightmost href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/dereck/' target='_blank' title='LinkedIn'>
                <NavImage src='/next.svg' />
            </NavItem>
        </NavContainer>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

### screenshots

Here are some screenshots of my previous version; which you can visit a live version of here; I would the new react version of the navbar to act as this live version: https://derecksnotes.com/

Here the navbar looks as it should in full screen.

[image]

Here when you hover over the dropdown it covers the label.

[image]

When you make the window smaller I want a hamburger menu to appear and hide the "Link1-4" links and the dropdown menu. This is where my inexperience with react get's me, should I do this css or with hooks and conditionals etc; I am confused on how to implement this.

Also, I had a lot of trouble getting any hamburger menu code to work with my current hierarchy of components in my code. The way I nested elements makes sense to me I've seen other examples where there are a lot more elements that just make this confusing.

[image: want to implement hamburger menu on small windows]

Desired result. Here below is a screenshot of my current live version.

[image: desired results]

Here is what I want the dropdown to look like when I hover over it:

[image: desired behaviour of dropdown]

[image: hamburger menu working]

Comment: Please refactor the provided code and screenshot to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to narrow down the actual error.

Comment: @IngoSteinke thank you I re-wrote my post as a minimal example. Just set up a nextjs project and copy over my NavBar component. I hope it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I came back to this and have solved it. Here is my code:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FaBars, FaFilter, FaUser } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { theme } from '@styles/theme';

import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { toggleTagsFilter } from '@store/tagsFilterVisibilitySlice';

import Auth from '../modals/auth/Auth';

const HamburgerIcon = styled.div`
    display: none;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 13px;

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        display: block;
    }
`;

const ResponsiveMenu = styled.div<{ open: boolean }>`
    display: ${props => (props.open ? 'block' : 'none')};

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        display: ${props => (props.open ? 'block' : 'none')};
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        display: block;
    }
`;

const NavContainer = styled.nav`
    background-color: ${theme.container.background.colour.primary()};
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 90%;
    color: ${theme.theme_colours[5]()};

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.5), 0 0 20px rgba(100, 100, 40, 0.2) inset;

    &:hover {
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.5);
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_snap_up}) {
        width: 95%;
    }
`;

const CommonNavItem = styled.div`
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
    }
`;

// allows for argument to determine if align left or right
// inherit from Link component allows for linking to other pages
const NavLeftItem = styled(CommonNavItem).attrs({ as: Link }) <{ rightmost?: boolean }>`
    float: left;
    &:hover {
        color: ${theme.text.colour.white()};
        background-color: ${theme.theme_colours[5]()};
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        float: none;
    }
`;

const NavRightItemLink = styled(CommonNavItem).attrs({ as: Link }) <{ rightmost?: boolean }>`
    float: right;
`;

const NavRightItem = styled(CommonNavItem) <{ rightmost?: boolean }>`
    float: right;
    &:hover {
        color: ${theme.text.colour.white()};
        background-color: ${theme.theme_colours[5]()};
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        float: none;
    }
`;

const DropDownContainer = styled.div`
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
    }
`;

// the same as NavItem but no link
const DropDownLabel = styled(CommonNavItem) <{ rightmost?: boolean }>`
    &:hover {
        color: ${theme.text.colour.white()};
        background-color: ${theme.theme_colours[5]()};
    }
`;

const DropDownContent = styled.div`
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #ccc;
    background-color: ${theme.container.background.colour.primary()};

    ${DropDownContainer}:hover & {
        display: block;
    }

    ${NavLeftItem} {
        float: none;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    /* TODO: still not working as intended */
    ${NavLeftItem}:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }

    ${NavLeftItem}:last-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        border: none;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
        box-shadow: none;

        ${NavLeftItem} {
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    }
`;

const DateTimeDisplay = styled.div`
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    @media screen and (max-width: ${theme.container.widths.min_width_mobile}) {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        float: none;
        text-align: left;
    }
`;

// since using conditionals in components we must ensure that the component is mounted before rendering
// either this or use dynamic from next/dynamic
function NavBar() {
    const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);
    const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [isAuthModalOpen, setIsAuthModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const closeMenu = () => {
        setIsMenuOpen(false);
    };    

    // redux control of tag filter
    // Error: `useDispatch` was conditionally called inside an `if` statement. Fixed: Moved `useDispatch` to the top-level, ensuring consistent hook order across renders.
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleToggleFilterClick = () => {
        dispatch(toggleTagsFilter());
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setHasMounted(true);

        const updateDateTime = () => {
            const currentDate = new Date();
            const displayDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
                day: '2-digit',
                month: 'short'
            });
            const displayTime = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', {
                hour12: false,
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                second: '2-digit'
            });
            setDateTime(`${displayDate} ${displayTime}`);
        };

        updateDateTime();
        const interval = setInterval(updateDateTime, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);

    if (!hasMounted) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <NavContainer>
            <HamburgerIcon onClick={() => setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen)}>
                <FaBars />
            </HamburgerIcon>

            <NavLeftItem onClick={closeMenu} href='/'>Blog</NavLeftItem>
            <ResponsiveMenu open={isMenuOpen}>
                <NavLeftItem onClick={closeMenu} href='/courses'>Courses</NavLeftItem>
                <NavLeftItem onClick={closeMenu} href='/references'>References</NavLeftItem>
                <DropDownContainer>
                    <DropDownLabel>Dictionaries</DropDownLabel>
                    <DropDownContent>
                        <NavLeftItem onClick={closeMenu} href='/dictionaries/biology'>Biology Dictionary</NavLeftItem>
                        <NavLeftItem onClick={closeMenu} href='/dictionaries/chemistry'>Chemistry Dictionary</NavLeftItem>
                    </DropDownContent>
                </DropDownContainer>
                {/* <NavRightItemLink href='https://www.linkedin.com/in/dereck/' target='_blank' title='LinkedIn'>
                <FaLinkedin />
            </NavRightItemLink> */}
                <DateTimeDisplay>{dateTime || "00 Jan 00:00:00"}</DateTimeDisplay>
                <NavRightItem onClick={handleToggleFilterClick}>
                    <FaFilter />
                </NavRightItem>
                <NavRightItem onClick={() => setIsAuthModalOpen(true)}>
                    <FaUser />
                </NavRightItem>
                {isAuthModalOpen && <Auth onClose={() => setIsAuthModalOpen(false)} />}
            </ResponsiveMenu>
        </NavContainer>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```